# How to add Unity component functions in UnityEvent using script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a custom editor where the object and their components are automatically added.

But how do I put the Unity component built-in function in `UnityEvent` via script?

In this case, I want to put audio source `Play()` function in the `UnityEvent` via script.

[image: before]
[image: after]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hope this works:

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.Events;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
[RequireComponent (typeof (AudioSource))]
public class SceneAnimationEvent : MonoBehaviour {
    public AudioSource audioSrc;
    [SerializeField]
    public UnityEvent unityEvent;
    UnityAction methodDelegate;
    bool eventAdded = false;

    void OnEnable() {
        UpdateInspector ();
    }
    void UpdateInspector() {
        if (!eventAdded) {
            audioSrc = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
            unityEvent = new UnityEvent ();
            methodDelegate = System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (typeof(UnityAction), audioSrc, "Play") as UnityAction;
            UnityEditor.Events.UnityEventTools.AddPersistentListener (unityEvent, methodDelegate);
            eventAdded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its working, I will post my full code if someone else encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [@zayedupal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45583832/4298200), this is my final code to automatically create a `GameObject`, `Component`s and automatically add a `UnityEvent`.

```
[MenuItem("GameObject/Create Animation/With SFX", false, -1)]
static void CreateAnimationWithSFX()
{
    GameObject go = new GameObject("animationWithSFX");
    go.transform.SetParent(Selection.activeTransform);

    AudioSource audioSource = go.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
    audioSource.playOnAwake = false;
    // Automate-add the right channel for audio source
    AudioMixer mixer = Resources.Load("Master") as AudioMixer;
    audioSource.outputAudioMixerGroup = mixer.FindMatchingGroups("SFX")[0];

    SceneAnimationEvent script = go.AddComponent<SceneAnimationEvent>();
    // Automate-add the unity built-in function into UnityEvent
    script.Events = new UnityEvent ();
    UnityAction methodDelegate = System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (typeof(UnityAction), audioSource, "Play") as UnityAction;
    UnityEventTools.AddPersistentListener (script.Events, methodDelegate);

    Undo.RegisterCreatedObjectUndo(go, "Create " + go.name);
    Selection.activeObject = go;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unityEvent.AddListener`

```c#
public class EventRunner : MonoBehaviour {

    public AudioSource audioSource;
    public UnityEvent ev;

    IEnumerator Start () {

        //you won't see an entry comes up in the inspector
        ev.AddListener(audioSource.Play);

        while (true)
        {
            ev.Invoke(); //you will hear the sound
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: i need to add listener on editor without entering playing mode.